# ftp in xammp or vsftpd

Tags: ftp, xampp, vsftpd

I just know XAMPP can provide web, SQL and FTP services on the server. Also I know vsftpd gives ftp service. So which one to choose if some one wants to give his server ftp service?

Which one do you advise? Are they have any different which make one of them better than another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSFTPD is the most secure.
Install vsftpd and a PAM library and you can do:

- Create user accouts with custom directories (in /var/www/ for example)
- Set directories with the correct chmod and chown
- Create a admin user with full access to the server
- Troubleshoot
- create FTP users but no local unix users (no shell access, no home directory and so on).  aka virtual users.